# EXCEL: feed worksheet with data from multiple csv files

Tags: excel, csv, import

I have a folder filled with `*.csv` files: say `a.csv`, `b.csv`, `c.csv`. Each `*.csv` file contains i.e. 3 values in a row.

Now, I want to create an excel worksheet where i.e.

```
column A - 1st value from a.csv
column B - 2nd value from a.csv
column C - 1st value from b.csv
... 
and so on.
```

How to do it faster tan ctrl-c, ctrl-v?
Thanks!

Comment: it is not used in the final worksheet :)

Comment: Easiest way is to make VBA macros or standalone VBS that will open each csv-file from the folder and copy necessary columns to created excel worksheet.